# Message Queue MQ , Tibco, SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can we use SQL Service Broker for Message Queue instead of MSMQ or IMB MQ or Tibco

Business scenario is reading multiple prices from different data sources (API, FIX protocol, database and so on) into SQL server Database.